# Putting the content of a .txt into a String

Tags: java, string, file, text

I don't like to ask questions that have been answered a lot, but I kinda need to right now.

I'd like to have a method for a project to extract the content of a .txt file into a String variable (then manipulate the String). What I need is a clean and compact way to do that. I already know that the only 3 characters the String will be able to contain are "." "*" "\n" (or "\r\n" if the file had been created in Windows).

Basically I already created a class called TextFile which has a String variable and there is a method called importFile that takes a String as an argument (and that string is the path of the .txt file).

I know I will have to deal with exceptions and all but I'm not really at ease with that either.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Can you show us what you have programmed so far? Showing us the source code helps to solve a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I use. You may want to modify it or totally, throw it away. Either way, you won't hurt my feelings.

```
public static String readFileAsString(String filePath)
  throws java.io.IOException{
    StringBuffer fileData = new StringBuffer(1000);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    char[] buf = new char[1024];
    int numRead=0;
    while((numRead=reader.read(buf)) != -1){
      fileData.append(buf, 0, numRead);
    }
    reader.close();
    return fileData.toString();
  }
```

Comment: Seems good, could you please explain a few things to me (as I don't want to copy/paste without understanding). 
What are 1000 and 1024? Is it a limit of size for the String? 
What makes the while-loop to end? 
Well maybe I should try to find some documentation on append.

Comment: if you do new File(filePath) you can then do new StringBuffer(file.length()) to keep your buffer from growing when you know the initial size anyhow.

Comment: @Trevor You are right, but to be honest I never really worry about it unless I'm loading a HUGE file - at which point I'm probably reading line by line anyway.

Comment: @Sword22 `StringBuffer(1000)` sets the initial capacity - it will usually have to grow, but you can set it as Trevor suggested. The `char[1024]` means it will use a buffer of 1024 characters, just a nice round number. The while loop stops when there is nothing left to read - see the documentation for `BufferedReader` and more specifically the `read` method.

Comment: @Sword22 - yeah, i wouldn't do that all the time, but he's already deemed he's loading the whole thing in memory :)

Answer (score 2):

Can you simply use commons-io to do that?
see http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/input/package-summary.html

Comment: Forgot to say that I only want to use the basic packages, as I'm often switching from one computer to an other.